# Difference of binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let's say I have a sum of binomial coefficients that look like this:

$12\choose5$+$11\choose5$+$10\choose5$+$9\choose5$+$8\choose5$

How can I rewrite this equation so that it's a difference of binomial coefficients but that will still get the same answer as the above equation.

Comment: Hint: Find a general formula for $S_n=\binom{5}{5}+\binom{6}{5}+\dots \binom{n}{5}$.  Then this is $S_{20}-S_{7}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Prove with Pascal's formula and induction that for all $n\ge k$,
$$\binom kk+\binom{k+1}k+\dots+\binom nk=\binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful hockey stick diagram on [this page](http://ptri1.tripod.com/#hockey) gives an important clue.

If you're still stuck with the connection to your sum, ask how you would have to extend your sum $\binom{12}{5}+\binom{11}{5}+\binom{10}5+\binom95+\binom85$ to use the result on the linked page, and what bits of that extended sum are missing from your sum.