# binomial coefficients difference?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

**I need a difference of 2 binomial coefficients that would be equivalent to the following sum:**

$12\choose5$+$11\choose5$+$10\choose5$+$9\choose5$+$8\choose5$

How to answer this?

Comment: They do not strike me as *different*.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663608/difference-of-binomial-coefficients#comment3764858_1663608

Comment: Your attempt is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{m=k}^n {m \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k+1}.$$

Write out all of the terms of $$\sum_{m=5}^{12} {m \choose 5}.$$

From the hint, what does this equal?  Which terms do you need to take away to get what you want, and what does *that* equal?

Comment: $m$ should start at $k$.

Comment: @Bernard I'll change it but doesn't it end up being the same?  Doesn't ${m \choose k} = 0$ if $m<k$?

Comment: It's eventually the same, but note it's only by convention that $\dbinom nk=0$ if $k>n$. Further, it may be disturbing  for  beginners.

Comment: I certainly don't want to disturb anyone. :)

Comment: It may be fun at times, though ;o)